# Changing dynamically added select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. How can I make changes on dynamically added Select option to be noticed when I am changing the selection programically?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").append('<select id="color"><option value="khaki">Khaki</option> <option value="green">Green</option> <option value="gold">Gold</option><option value="red">Red</option> </select>');
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#color option:eq(2)").attr("selected", "selected");
  }, 6000);
  
  $('#color').on('change', function() {
    $('body').css('background', this.value);
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: 1. `$('#color').on('change' ...` needs to go inside the first timeout function, after you're creating the `<select>` (the element needs to exist when you add an event listener). Alternatively, use `$(document).on('change', '#color', function ...` 2. doesn't look like changing the selection fires the event, but you can always manually call `$('#color').change()` afterwards.

Comment: Pro tips: there is no need to add "issue" or "question" or "problem" in your titles - readers know you have an issue, so the word is redundant. Use the title space to describe the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use delegate to handle `change` event.
2. Fire event programically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").append('<select id="color"><option value="khaki">Khaki</option> <option value="green">Green</option> <option value="gold">Gold</option><option value="red">Red</option> </select>');
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#color option:eq(2)").attr("selected", "selected")
    .change();
  }, 6000);
  
  $('body').on('change','#color', function() {
    $('body').css('background', this.value);
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```